# VB.NET Reference/point to a variable

Tags: vb.net, class, variables

I am aware that I can't dynamically refer to a variable (eg. 'var & var.Close()').
Can I somehow have a variable that can point to another variable by name?

My current code is (where func() requires an array):

```
Dim playerNum As String = “P1”
Select Case playerNum
  Case “P1”
    Func(P1(x, xx))
  Case “P2”
    Func(P2(x, xx))
  .........
End Select
```

Can something along these lines be done?

```
Dim playerNum As varNameRef = P1(,)
Func(playerNum(x, xx))
```

Really anything to stop so much repetition would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: You can do this using Reflection, but unless you have hundreds of methods like this the readability/maintainability cost won't be worth it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store Variable Name in String in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353131/store-variable-name-in-string-in-vb-net)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll take your word for it - I only have 20 cases.

Comment: You could store delegates to the appropriate functions in a dictionary. This way, you can refer to the function by its key with only one line.

Comment: Can you expand on your question to show why "dynamically refer to a variable" is essential to how your application must operate? I can't help but think you would save yourself a whole lot of trouble by refactoring your code to make better use of references, classes, indexers, etc. E.g., SteveDog's idea to make use of a Dictionary to connect `playerNum` to the appropriate `PlayerData` is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @rskar It isn't. I was just hacking away at the start of a project. SteveDog's answer solved my immediate problem and will definitely make things more effective long-term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a reference type (class), instead of a value type (structure).  For instance, if you created a class that stored your array as a property, like this:

```
Public Class PlayerData
    Public Data(10, 30) As Object
End Class
```

This also gives you the advantage of easily expanding the data that you store about each player.  Then, you could reference the same `PlayerData` object with multiple variables:

```
Dim player1 As New PlayerData()
Dim player2 As New PlayerData()
Dim player As PlayerData = Nothing
Select Case playerNum
    Case “P1”
        player = player1
    Case “P2”
        player = player2
End Select
Func(player.Data(x, xx))
```

However, it would be even better yet to store them in a dictionary as key value pairs, such as:

```
Dim players As New Dictionary(Of String, PlayerData)()
players("P1") = New PlayerData()
players("P2") = New PlayerData()
```

Then, you could access you players like this:

```
Func(players(playerNum).Data(x, xx))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by reflection, but i would advise against for performance-, readability- and maintainabilty-reasons.

You could use `Actions(Of T)` if you really want, for example:

```
Class Player
    Public Name As String
End Class

Sub play(player As Player)
    Console.WriteLine(player.Name & " plays now")
End Sub
```

Create some players to demonstrate:

```
Dim playerList As New List(Of Player)
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
    Dim p = New Player() With {.Name = "P" & i}
    playerList.Add(p)
Next

playerList.ForEach(AddressOf play)
```