# Is there a better way to get a variable's name as a string in .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

I want to be able to get a variable's name as a string.

This can be achieved effectively by [using a parameterless lambda expression](http://ivanz.com/2009/12/04/how-to-avoid-passing-property-names-as-strings-using-c-3-0-expression-trees/). However, this has a performance overhead, and it's not built-in functionality.

.NET 4.5 has provided  [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/callermembername-not-that-great-for.html) to provide a caller's name as a method argument. This gives us a built-in and better (in some cases) way to do this for specific situations.

**.NET 4.5 has provided an improvement in this area for a specific context. Is there now also a better^ means to get any variable's name as a string?**

As requested, here's a general usage example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
//Assume 'myVariable' is a local variable, member variable, static member variable, constant, parameter or even a property.
string myVariableName = ...; //This should get the string name of myVariable
```

^By better, I mean faster, not requiring reflection, built-into .NET or more elegant, but preferably a combination of these.

Comment: Wow the caller member name attribute looks cool.  I havent heard about it yet.

Comment: +1, For letting me know about this new Attribute :)

Comment: as far as I can remember: you can get information on the parameters by using PostSharp (http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) - but for variables... could you give an example of usage?

Comment: StackTrace can give any information required, not sure about efficiency...

Comment: @chac, I don't consider that to be any better than the existing approaches. I think it's actually worse; I recall reading that it depends on your build options.

Comment: @Sam not only build options. The .NET CLR JIT compiler can inline methods regardless the build-target (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2004/11/01/250398.aspx) ...

Comment: your approach is covered by another question here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter if you are after more elegant exception-throwing you might choose my answer ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, you haven't answered the question. Regarding the question you linked to, I am asking if there is a better way to solve the problem with the new .NET 4.5 release. That question's accepted answer only covers the lambda expression mechanism I mentioned in the question, and it's not in the context of .NET 4.5

Comment: @Sam now your intention is clear, I have to agree :) and that's the reason I've removed my answer. Nevertheless, how can be `string testVariable = "value";
string nameOfTestVariable = MemberInfoGetting.GetMemberName(() => testVariable);` more simplified?! as you elaborate over time you can't expect people to keep up with your edits, though! And I thought the keypoint was *I'm looking for a better way to do this* not *I'm looking for a better way to do this in .NET 4.5* :) Besides that, why do you need .NET 4.5-context? Only to have it, or is it somehow reasonable?!

Comment: What you are asking is code inspection during runtime. You can't do "any better" than reflection.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, the key point really is that I want a _better_ way to do this. I mentioned .NET 4.5 because I already investigated this before .NET 4.5 and found the lambda expression solution to be overall the best option, but after seeing the improvement provided by `CallerMemberNameAttribute`, I don't know if .NET 4.5 has enabled an improved mechanism to achieve this.

Comment: @John: of cause you could. Variablenames are known at compiletime, so the designers of the C# language could provide some builtin function to get the name of a variable without using reflection. And thats what the OP was asking for, because they have added the very similar CallerMemberNameAttribute with .NET 4.5

Comment: FYI, the LINQ sytntax doesn't use reflection, that's the whole point of using Expression trees; they're fast!  They get created during compilation so there's not even any overhead for generating them.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, by the way, regarding what you said about the lambda expression approach only working for member variables, I did some testing and found that it works for all variables except for `const` ones. (I presume this is because they're inlined at compile-time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no better/faster way. I think, the expresseion tree way you have linked is the only way to get to the name of the variable.

The `CallerMemberNameAttribute`, `CallerFilePathAttribute`, `CallerLineNumberAttribute` are the sole new features introduced in .NET 4.5 in that area.

Comment: "Indeed there is no other way than using reflection to get the name of the variable" - that's incorrect.  The Expression trees technique doesn't use reflection, they're generated at compile time.  The whole point of Expression trees is that they are much quicker than using reflection.

Comment: @DoctaJonez: Yes, you are right - its not reflection. I have updated my answer.

Comment: There is a trick where class-level property static initialization sets the `[CallerMemberName]` to the property name (instead of the method name for local variables). NOTE it does *not* work with anonymous types nor impl/expl operators - they get the method name or ctor. The new `nameof` operator allows rename refactoring while maintaining the performance of a string literal (because it becomes one at compile time). eg `var abc = new MyThing(nameof(abc));` unfortunately this cannot be automatically obtained by the callee without the caller adding code (unlike `[CallerMemberName]`).