# Why is it not possible to get local variable names using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, local-variables, cil

If I have a code like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string bar = "";
        int foo = 24;
    }
}
```

I can get the local variables declared in `Main` using:

```
var flag = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
var fields = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Main", flags).GetMethodBody().LocalVariables;
```

This returns a `IList<LocalVariableInfo>` and the [`LocalVariableInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) has only three properties: `IsPinned`,`LocalIndex` and `LocalType`. So no `Name` property exists.

What I'm wondering is that you can see the variable names in the generated `IL code`:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string bar,
           [1] int32 foo)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      ""
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.s   24
  IL_0009:  stloc.1
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

but it is not possible to get them using `Reflection`. Is it because local variables don't have a name and they are only accessed by their indices (if so how the `ILDASM.exe` shows the names?), or because such feature is not implemented? Or if it is possible using another way, then the question would be, ***how***?

Note: I have seen some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter) and most of them is using `Expressions` to get a variable name. It doesn't work if I would like to get all locals including temporary variables that were generated by the compiler.

Comment: Are names present after removing PDB files?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight they are, but I see temporary names like V_0 and V_1 instead of actual names

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to differentiate between the human-readable text-based form of CLI and the machine-readable compiled form of CLI.

In text CLI, local variables indeed can have names (see §II.15.4.1.3 of ECMA-335, as explained in Damien's answer).

But in the binary form, local variables don't have names. For that, look at §II.23.2.6, where the binary format for a method's local variable signature (list of all its local variables) is specified. And it doesn't contain any mention of variable names:

[image: LocalVarSig]

So, if some tool wants to know the original name of a local variable, it has to look into the debugging information contained in the PDB file. If that's not present, there is no way to find out the name.

Comment: I kept trying to find information about how it was actually encoded but I just couldn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Local variable names are not persisted in metadata. In Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL), local variables are accessed by their position in the local variable signature.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking at a Debug build. The `id` part of the `.locals` declaration is *optional* - so there's no guarantee that the names are retained.

See [MS Partition II](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/3/733AD403-90B2-4064-A81E-01035A7FE13C/MS%20Partition%20II.pdf) which describes the IL Metadata, section 15.4.1.3 for further details:

```
MethodBodyItem ::= …
   .locals [ init ] ‘(’ LocalsSignature ‘)’
LocalsSignature ::= Local [ ‘,’ Local ]*
Local ::= Type [ Id ]
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman - thanks. My problem is that I always, of course, just refer to a local copy of these files but then struggle with providing a link.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because the variable name you see in ILDasm come from the pdb file, not from the assembly itself. If you want to get them, you'll need to read the pdb too.