# C# Get the original name of the parameter

Tags: c#

I want to write a function (for example GetVarName)
that returns the original name of the variable.

## For Example:

```
public string GetVarName(params object[] vars) { ??? }

public void Main()
{
    int var1 = 5;
    int var2 = var1+11;

    Console.WriteLine(GetVarName(var1));
    Console.WriteLine(GetVarName(var2));
}
```

## Output (needed):

```
var1 = 5;
var2 = 16;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far for `GetVarName()`?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(nameof(var1));` ?

Comment: There is the `nameof` operator, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9801735/340760

Comment: Take this implementation:

  `static string GetVarName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
        {
            var body = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;
            var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(body);
            var getter = getterLambda.Compile();
            return body.Member.Name + " = " + getter();
        }`

Comment: C# does not recognize nameof function

I tried the function of Gianluigi Liguori

But how the call statement need to be?

Console.WriteLine(GetVarName(var1)); // - It is not working!