# Using Text instead of instance names of classes

Tags: c#

```
var a = new myTestClass();
var b = new myTestClass2();
list<string> instList = new list<string>();
instList.add("b");

public void simpleFunc()
{
foreach(string i in instList){
a.fieldName = **i.myFieldName;**  
//HERE i is b which refers to the instance of myTestClass2 
}
```

what I would like to accomplish here is: create a List of string whihc are the names of class instances then inside a for each loop use the instlist strings like an instance of the class and add something to that property of that class

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do that, you can create a dictionary with the name as key and the instance as value. I do wonder though why you are thinking the variable name is so important... A variable name can change easily and after all, it is just a pointer to the actual object. Shouldn't you create a class to save the 'metadata' of the variable?

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add(nameof(a), a);
d.Add(nameof(b), b);

string valueAtB = d["b"];
```

Comment: Note: nameof is only available in C# 6.0, so if you are using an earlier version this code won't compile

Comment: Indeed, then you can just use `d.Add("b", b);`, which isn't that expressive but does the same.

Comment: Check this solution which provides a way to get the name pre c#6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter