# Get name (string) of new class/struct

Tags: c#

I looking for a way to get the name of a class (or struct) which is instantiate under C# 6. Exemple :

```
public class Test
{
public int myvalue;

public Test(int _myvalue){ myvalue= _myvalue;}
}

void Init()
{
    public Test test= new Test(1);
}

void main()
{
    string nameNewTest = // here what I need, that must return "test", not "Test"
}
```

I saw lot of topics for find the type like : GetType().Name/nameOf/typeof(Class).Name or some stuff like that but no one for the name of a new variable.

Comment: Because it is not the name of the instance, it's just a variable name. Maybe you mean `nameof(test)` (C#6), but since your code snippet is not valid c# it's hard to tell where to use that.

Comment: Do you mean `nameof(Test)` ?

Comment: This doesn't even compile (ignoring `main`). Please try to correct your example and explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please clean up your question, post a [mcve] and state exactly what you want and why.

Comment: Do you mean the name of the instance "test" or the name of the class "Test"? (because, you know `Test test = new Test()` is a really bad example if you want to get "test"/"Test")

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer he mentioned in the comments of the current answer he does not want "Test", he wanted "test".

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string nameNewTest = nameof(Test);
```

Without C# 6

```
string nameNewTest = typeof(Test).Name;
```

You can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9801735/6479770) for properties/fields

Comment: Yes but without C# 6.

Comment: I edited the answer, you can use `typeof(T).Name`

Comment: Take look at the end of my topic, I already try typeof(T).Name but that give me "Test" for my exemple. In your link, that's works only for fields, not for class =/struct

Comment: I don't understand, where did "test" come from ? If you want your class `Test` to lower use `typeof(Test).Name.ToLower()`. If you want the name for variable `public Test test` define in `void Init()` you can't get it in `void main()`because there are separated functions. Where are these both functions declared ?

Comment: test is a new class of Test  (line 10), and this is an exemple just for explain what I need.

Comment: Did the link solve your problem ? You can do `MemberInfoGetting.GetMemberName(() => test)`

Comment: Unfortunately no :/ this works only for field not for instance