# Simplify IF-clause and find name of Variable in LINQ select statement

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

I am trying to find out which `List<int>` out of many has a certain amount of elements

Example input:

```
List<int> list_1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 299).ToList();
List<int> list_2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 300).ToList();
List<int> list_3 = Enumerable.Range(1, 300).ToList();
List<int> list_4 = Enumerable.Range(1, 297).ToList();
```

What I need is to log the **name** of the list and the **amount** of items `if` it has less than let's say 300 values. Now I could do of course a single `if` clause for every list:

```
if (list_1.Count != 300)
{
    //log name and number of items
}
if(list_2 ... and so on)
```

Question: Is there a more elegant way of finding out this information?

I tried a LINQ solution and put all Lists into one for filtering. But in this my problem is that I cannot get the name:

```
List<List<int>> allLists = new List<List<int>>();

allLists.Add(list_1);
allLists.Add(list_2);
allLists.Add(list_3);
allLists.Add(list_4);

string logRes = String.Join(" ", allLists.Where(x=>x.Count < 300)
        .Select(x=> String.Format("Name: {0} Amount: {1}", nameof(x), x.Count)));
```

It returns:

> Name: x Amount: 299 Name: x Amount: 297

Question 2: How can I get the name of the evil list in the collection?

Comment: Would not make more sense using a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` instead of a list of lists? The key may contain the name of the list.

Comment: If you are using C# 6.0 you can also make use of NameOf expressions: http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/c-6-preview-nameof-expressions/ However i agree that a dictionary would be a much more elegant solution here.

Comment: @MasterYoda: he uses namof, but that doesnt help in the LINQ query

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah i see that now. Sorry I must have overlooked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter) or  a different collection like f.e. a`Dictionary<string, List<int>>`:

```
var listNames = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
listNames.Add(nameof(list_1), list_1);
listNames.Add(nameof(list_2), list_2);
listNames.Add(nameof(list_3), list_3);
listNames.Add(nameof(list_4), list_4);

string logRes = String.Join(" ", listNames
    .Where(kv => kv.Value.Count < 300)
    .Select(kv => $"Name: {kv.Key} Amount: {kv.Value.Count}"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the dictionary suggestion. Is this the best way to avoid multiple if-clauses?

Comment: @MongZhu: specify _best_, in my opinion its a readable and concise version, yes.

Comment: trying to specify: less code but still readable. It gets pretty wild to read if I would have 10 lists for example. But then again may be I should rethink the design of saving the data in the first place maybe. I like your solution, thanx again

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your code to include the names of lists along with actual lists:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> allLists = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

allLists.Add("list_1", list_1);
allLists.Add("list_2", list_2);
allLists.Add("list_3", list_3);
allLists.Add("list_4", list_4);

string logRes = String.Join(" ", allLists
    .Where(x => x.Value.Count < 300)
    .Select(x => String.Format("Name: {0} Amount: {1}", x.Key, x.Value.Count)));
```

Comment: Your answer is exact the same as @Tim Schmelter.. But he was 4 mintues before you..

Comment: @SeanStayn Well not exactly same, that one is going to work only after C# 6.0. Looks like I took quite some time in typing my answer.