# {CallerMemberName} like Functionality for nameof() param

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, method-signature

I'm writing more library code and came across an annoyance - here is an example

```
public static TParam RequiredParam<TParam>(TParam param, string name) where TParam : class 
{
  return param ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
}

private readonly int _testInt;

public TestClass(int testInt)
{
  _testInt = RequiredParam(testInt, nameof(testInt));
}
```

Basically I have to pass in the name in the usage

What I want to have is:

```
public static TParam RequiredParam<TParam>(TParam param) where TParam : class 
{
  return param ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(*NAME STILL GETS HERE SOMEHOW*);
}

private readonly int _testInt;

public TestClass(int testInt)
{
  _testInt = RequiredParam(testInt);
}
```

Is there a better way? Back in the days of WPF I used to use [CallerMemberName]  like so:

```
private void PropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = default)
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

Does anyone know something similar to achieve the same result for this? Considering how often this library is called I don't mind stepping into post-build steps or whatever, but would prefer to avoid reflection for performance reasons.

Edit - Made my objective clearer

Comment: To be honest with you, I didn't quite get what you want to achieve.

Comment: This means you'll have a different method to check reference types vs value types. I think you should use the same for readability reasons.

Comment: @SeM - I want to change the call from - 
RequiredParam(testInt, nameof(testInt));
 - to - 
RequiredParam(testInt);

But still log the name of the variable in the exception

Comment: @Xsjado if you could do this, we wouldn't have to use `nameof` in the first place, which mind you is only a later addition to C#

Comment: @TheGeneral I know this, but I've seen other libraries do wonderful things with postbuild, it's both a nicer looking solution and a good segway to learning these techniques.

Comment: You could - well somehow - with an expression RequiredParam( () => testInt ) - read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter

Comment: @SirRufo - I considered something similar, by taking advantage of the named values now in tuples, but I don't think there are single value tuples :(

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i personally wouldn't do that anyway, you are hiding logic behind another method to save a couple of keystrokes. In doing this, for new readers they will have to click through to see what it does, and you still have to use `nameof` anyway.

You could probably do something with reflection, but even then it will be a lot of work for dubious gain.

Can i suggest a 3rd approach?

Why don't you just create a Resharper template for the keywords `args`[tab]

```
$NAME$ = $NAME$ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof($NAME$));
```

The benefits are

- New readers can easily see whats going on.
- You only have minimal key strokes as it will suggest the type after a few letters
- You save a bit of IL and a call to the stack

Also if you use Resharper, check out [Code Annotation Attributes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html)

---

You could also use an expression i guess

**Example**

```
public void ExampleFunction(Expression<Func<string, string>> f) {
    Console.WriteLine((f.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name);
}
```

**Usage**

```
ExampleFunction(x => WhatIsMyName);
```

Still in my opinion, nothing is really gained

Comment: Wouldn't using Resharper like this force anyone using my library to also use Resharper?

Comment: @Xsjado in the second case yes