# Get the original nameof(...) of a variable?

Tags: c#

I have this

```
public static class Parameters
{
    public static void Required<T>(this T parameter, string paramName) where T : class
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

And I use it like:

```
Parameters.Required(settings, nameof(settings));
```

Is it possible to get rid of the second parameter and somehow get the original parameter name, from within the `Required` method? No, right?

Comment: @Liam Disagree, OP isn't trying to get the name of the type.  OP wants the name of the variable being passed in.

Comment: In this example I don't see why you would throw the exception with `paramName` when `parameter` is `null`and not `paramName`?

Comment: No, you need `nameof`. `nameof` is a compile-time thing, which tells the compiler to substitute the string literal "settings". If you don't do this at compile-time, there's no way to do it a run-time.

Comment: I *suppose* it could be accomplished using expression trees, but it would require additional alterations to the method call.

Comment: @IDarkCoder because at this point the name of `parameter` is "parameter" and I want the original name. Hence, my question.

Comment: Compiling expressions to do something as cheap as a null-check seems like overkill

Comment: Impossible, most likely. What would happen for `Parameters.Required(obj.Something ? (object) obj.SomethingElse : obj.EntirelyDifferent)`? Probably unrealistic, but it's something you have to keep in mind, is possible.

Comment: @canton7 I wholeheartedly agree.  Dr. Malcolm: "Yeah, but your [computer] scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn't stop to think if they should."

Comment: Unless `Parameters.Required` is going to do something interesting other than throw the exception, using it is counterproductive -- you're not only giving the compiler and the JIT a harder workout, you're also complicating stack traces. If your method does have special logic, consider something of the form `if (param == null) throw HelperClass.ArgumentNull(nameof(param))`, with `ArgumentNull(string name) { myCustomLogic(); return new ArgumentNullException(name); }`. This pattern is used in the framework itself in a few places (to localize exception strings, mostly).

Comment: @JeroenMostert the whole idea is I want it to be a one-liner with a single parameter. Come on, nobody has mentioned `contracts` so far, I am almost disappointed.

Comment: Contracts are *so* last year

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to happen, sorry. Not at a reasonable cost, anyway -- as others have pointed out, expression trees would work, but these "one-liners" would be prohibitively expensive, especially if you applied them throughout your entire code base. Most editors have support for inserting null checks with one (or two) presses of a button. Or wait for C# 8's nullable reference types so you can get rid of a lot of checks... If you want to go the Code Contracts route, you certainly can -- just make your own IL rewriter or Roslyn extension, easy as pie. :-P

Comment: @HristoYankov Code Contracts are dead.  https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6361

Comment: I don't believe that nullable reference types will get rid of the need for null-checks - nothing fundamentally will stop a `string` from containing `null`.

Comment: nullable reference types won't replace null-checks at all. That's not what they are about.

Comment: NRTs won't eliminate null checks altogether (you will always need them around the public edges, and when you've made a conscious choice to introduce `null`), but they can certainly help reduce the need for them within a code base. Technically, of course, you can already just not do null checks if you like, but diagnosing the resulting NREs is painful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the Requred-function accepting a Expression. And from the expression you can read out the name of the member name. It's descriped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression).

```
    public static void Required<T>(Expression<Func<T>> parameter) where T : class
    {
        if (parameter.Compile().Invoke() == null)
        {
            var caller = ((MemberExpression)parameter.Body).Member.Name;
            throw new ArgumentNullException(caller);
        }

        // ...
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
Parameters.Required(() => settings);
```

Comment: I think caching the compiled expression is an *absolute* must for this one

Comment: Technically correct -- the best kind of correct -- but not something you want to propagate throughout a code base, as it makes null checks quite a bit more expensive. The plumbing needed to produce and process an entire expression tree for one parameter is considerable.

Comment: I agree. The price of getting rid of the second parameter is high.