# How to get the name of an Object?

Tags: c#

I am writing a new program and I want to get the name of an Object.
Here my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Computer c1 = new Computer(NAME_OF_OBJECT);
    }
}

class Computer
{
    public Computer(string _ComputerName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The computer {_ComputerName} has been created.");
    }
}
```

At the position `NAME_OF_OBJECT` I want to give the name `c1` of the new created object `Computer`.

At the end this output should come out `The computer c1 has been created.`

But, how to do that? Is there any way to reallize that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

Comment: Try `nameof(c1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
Computer c1 = new Computer(nameof(c1));
```