# How to compare a SQL column name with a variable name

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an appointment project, and I'm having trouble comparing the column name in SQL with a variable name in C#.

I have these variables, each of which is associated with a radio button on my form:

```
int time1;
int time2;
int time3;
int time4;
int time5;  // etc...
```

Additionally I have columns with the same name in a SQL table, and I want to compare each variable name with the column names, and if they are equal then update the value.

Comment: "*i want to check if one of them checked update this column in sql which equal the same name*" try and make this statement a little better so we can understand what you want. Its a little fractured

Comment: hope now better 
thank you

Comment: There are better ways to bind form data to a database, although that is a broad topic that has many tutorials online. The names of the variables should not be bound to column names in SQL.

Comment: I re-worded your question for clarity, but please it and make sure I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do, but I think this can help you:
[get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

Also, you can get the column name using INFORMATION_SCHEMA:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15