# Get variable name in C#

Tags: c#

```
string variableName = "hello world";
```

Is it possible to get the variable's name and not its value?

```
string x = variableName.name();

// x = "variableName"
```

Comment: If you need the name of a variable, probably you have something wrong in your project

Comment: You do realize that your example of making `x = "hello"` is accomplished by just regular programming (`var x = var;`)? (best not to use keywords for your variable names!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var name = nameof(x);
```

to get "x" in a string named "name", where x is the variable you want.

However, it will only work with modern flavours of C#. 
For older ones, you'll have to use Expression, which is a PITA, both for performances and in terms of code complexity for a such simple need.

edit : more details here : [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)