# Either dynamic object name using or putting elements to a dictionary as a reference possible?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, object, reference, c#-5.0

I don't know either scenario is possible or not but let me ask you

**scenario 1**

```
bool blObject_1=false;
bool blObject_2=false;
```

somehow access these objects like

```
int irParam1=1;
int irParam2=2;

blObject_irParam1=true; // this will reference blObject_1
blObject_irParam2=true; // this will reference blObject_2
```

ok scenario 2

compose a dictionary that will hold references of objects so i can call via key and modify
such as

```
Dictionary myDic<string,bool> = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
bool blObject_1=false;
bool blObject_2=false;
myDic.add("object1",blObject_1);
myDic.add("object2",blObject_2);

myDic["object1"]=true; // this will actually change blObject_1
```

c# 4 or c# 4.5 possible ?

**i want to access a variable dynamically somehow**

thank you

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is difficult to understand what is being asked.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead this is best i can do. i think it is pretty clear.

Comment: No, your second scenario doesn't work as you intend. You need to check the difference between value types and reference types. http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: @Steve i know. i wonder somehow that kind of thing possible. so compose a references thing and access objects dynamically.

Comment: or dynamically access objects that you know its name and type.

Comment: where is this declared..? `blObject_irParam1` your variable names are a bit odd not to mention it's hard to determine what you are asking here.. try to rephrase your question..
What does this actually mean `i want to access an object dynamically somehow`

Comment: @DJKRAZE think it like string operation so it composes blObject_1 and access it.

Comment: I ~think~ the goal here is to make a reference to a value type - something like what you can do with pointers or even references in C++ .  Is this correct?

Comment: are you talking about `blObject_` + some integer / Index position..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE do you know how to access an object with its defined name ? like in javascript you will call access an object with its name as string.

Comment: why not make these and enum int irParam1=1;
int irParam2=2; then you could get at it based on the enum name

Comment: it is that way right now. imagine that i have 10 params with that naming. and i want to modify each of them in a for loop with single line. you got the idea.

Comment: no it's not that way right now.. that's not an `enum` ..but you could make properties of that and access those properties or should I say get Property Name via Reflection is that what you are wanting to do..?

Comment: well i really can not make anything else that would require extra work right now. the system is currently poorly designed so i am looking for quick ways to solve if possible. looking for a way that i can access integer or string or bool variables via their names as string.

Comment: Look at this posting and it will explain how to use Expression tree to do what I think you are trying to do.. also I would suggest working with whom ever on your end to clean up the poor design remember the old saying `Garbage in Equals Garbage Out!`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection

Comment: oh i see. so seems like i have no way to achieve what i want :(

Comment: I have sent you a link so you will need to understand the code there here is another link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716399/c-sharp-how-do-you-get-a-variables-name-as-it-was-physically-typed-in-its-dec Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make a dynamic reference directly to a value type.

The typically approach here is to wrap the value type (ie: the `bool`) within a class, and store the class.  You can then access the class, and change it's members, from any location.

This allows you to have "shared" state that can change from multiple places.

Comment: it requires a lot of work. is that possible to access this objects with Reflection without performance loose ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Where is the object stored?  Is it in a class?  If so, you can build a dictionary or make the class subclass DynamicObject, etc.  Otherwise, you could use reflection, but it's slow...

Comment: they are variables actually. the standard variables such as integer or string or boolean.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Yes - but are they fields within a type, local variables on the stack, etc?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG then no, not possible - local variables can't be built into a reference like that - they only exist within the scope where they're used...

Comment: anyway i learnt my lesson that i should have defined a class and use it as an object