# Is there a way to print array name

Tags: c#, php, console-application

I have an array

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine("How to print the text arr1 ?? ");
```

I need the array name i.e. 'arr1' in console output/Writeline, seems simple but need help.

Edit :

Output should be

```
arr1
```

NOT

```
1 2 3
```

Good to know, this is achieved in PHP too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716399/c-sharp-how-do-you-get-a-variables-name-as-it-was-physically-typed-in-its-dec

Comment: Give me a valid reason before down voting. thanks.

Comment: because, there are already this questions and answers, you nedd just search

Comment: and multi language tags are not appreciated

Comment: Valid reasons: Bad tags (this is not at all related to a console application, and asking for implementations in two different languages leaves much to be desired, let alone writing a 2-in-1 question). No evidence whatsoever of you making even a slight attempt at achieving this yourself - you simply asked us to do something for you. Not how SO works. And finally, googling `C# print variable name` gives you two hits for SO questions, both of which have your solution.

Comment: So do you want to do this in php or c#?

Comment: Ok, I agree, i have used console application for testing purpose not to implement, i was with the conversation where above conversation, can  be achieved or not, that made me to use console application nothing else, once of the reason i asked 'php' too because our team is also working on php and want to know, it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare/initialize variables in a far more complicated way you could...

```
echo "<pre>";
$var_name="Foo";  // naming the var "Foo"
$$var_name="Bar"; // declaring the var "Foo"

echo "value: ". $Foo . "<br><br>";

foreach(compact($var_name) as $key=>$value){ // refering to var name
    echo "name: " . $key . "<br><br>";  
}

echo "pair: ";
print_r(compact($var_name));
echo "<pre>" ;
```

But we'd still need to get it through compact($var_name) instead of compact($Foo)