# How to retrieve a function name in F#?

Tags: f#

Consider the code sample:

```
let foo x = x

let bar f =
  printf "function name is %s" (*?*)

bar foo //should print: "function name is foo"
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, sorry.  (Depending on exactly what you want to do, there may be a constraint here you can weaken and get a job done.)

Possibly see also
[Getting the name of the parameter passed into a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755254/getting-the-name-of-the-parameter-passed-into-a-method)