# using reflection to get the name of a parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, compact-framework

I have a c# .net 2.0CF application where I would like to get not only the type and value of a parameter passed to the function, but also the variable name.

For example:

```
void Show<PARAM>(PARAM p)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} = {2}", typeof(PARAM).ToString, ???, p.ToString() );
}

bool foo = true;
Show(foo);
```

would output "bool foo = true";

In C++, I can do this with the `##` pre-processor macro.

If this can't be done in 2.0, can it be done in 3.5 or 4.0?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755254/getting-the-name-of-the-parameter-passed-into-a-method

Comment: neat trick for doing this (i think C# 3.0 would be required): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869610/c-resolving-a-parameter-name-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this is not possible with reflection as variable names are not in the assemblies, and `p` is a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Reflection;


ParameterInfo[] info = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(false);
System.Diagnostics.StackFrame[] frames = trace.GetFrames();
```

i guess the value can be retrieved from stack frames.

The Paramter Name can be found from the

ParameterInfo[] info = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();

Comment: StackTrace and StackFrame aren't available in the Compact Framework.

Comment: also, this isn't true. `StackFrame` only contains file, line and column and the `MethodBase`. Neither contains the original parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Show(int value)
    {
        ParameterInfo[] info = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}={2}", info[0].ParameterType.ToString(), info[0].Name, value.ToString()));
    }
```

output

System.Int32 value=10

Comment: Unfortunately, the CF does not have a MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().

Comment: Try using PostSharp it has the support for Compact Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PostSharp it has the support for Compact Framework.