# How to get the PropertyName of a class？

Tags: c#

How to get the PropertyName of a class？

For example, How can I get the PropertyName "StudentName" of a Student class instance.

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName{get;set;}
}


Student student = new Student();

//I want to get the PropertyName "StudentName"
student.StudentName.GetName();
```

Comment: I don't understand, if you already know the property then by definition you already know the name of the property?

Comment: Is there any reason not to directly type in "StudentName" as a string? Maybe, you can get better answers if you try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It is used for other class, so I do not want to hard-type the string.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301809/workarounds-for-nameof-operator-in-c-typesafe-databinding/301957#301957, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869610/c-resolving-a-parameter-name-at-runtime, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301809/workarounds-for-nameof-operator-in-c-typesafe-databinding

Answer (score 2):

To get the actual name of the property, just from having access to the class, you can use the following:

```
Type studentType = typeof(Student);
PropertyInfo[] AllStudentProperties = studentType.GetProperties();
```

If you know the name you're looking for and just need access to the property itself, use:

```
Type studentType = typeof(Student);
PropertyInfo StudentProperties = studentType.GetProperty("StudentName");
```

Once you have the `PropertyInfo`, simply use `PropertyInfo.Name`, which will give the string representation.

If after this you wan't the value, you're going to have to have an instantiated class to get the value. Other than this, if you use a `static` property, you can pull the value without instantiating it.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer:**

C# now has a [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) operator, so you should use that.

You can use it on the instance or the Student type itself.

Example:

```
nameof(student.StudentName); // returns "StudentName"
nameof(Student.StudentName); // returns "StudentName"
```

**Original answer (written before `nameof` existed):**

You can use the following static method:

```
static string GetName<T>(T item) where T : class
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    return properties[0].Name;
}
```

Use like so:

```
string name = GetName(new { student.StudentName });
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869610/c-resolving-a-parameter-name-at-runtime) for details.