# How do I get the name of a variable USED in a parameter

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the Variable Name passed to a Function in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121/finding-the-variable-name-passed-to-a-function-in-c-sharp)
>   [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

It's sorta a long explanation, so I'll just dive right into the question:

Is there any way to store the name of the variable used in a parameter to a string?

example:

```
 void ExampleMethod(int parameter1)
{
Stuff
}

ExampleMethod(VariableInt);
```

How would I go about getting "VariableInt" into a string variable?

Comment: Could you explain why do you need that?

Comment: Put quotes around it? The `CompilerServices` namespace has a bunch of things like this but none for getting the local variable a parameter was assigned from.

Comment: here is a link for you that will help you good luck http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/13/how-to-find-out-variable-or-parameter-name-in-c.html