# How to Use the objects name in a class c#

Tags: c#, class, object, instance

In this case i Want to print
m2k:
salt:2
skill:
 is there a way to do that?
to somehow get the name of the object that we are using

```
namespace practice
{
class SmashPlayer
{
    private int salt, skill;
    public SmashPlayer(int salt, int skill)
    {
        this.salt = salt;
        this.skill = skill;
    }
public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}'s\nsalt:{1}\nskill:{2}",Name of object,salt,skill);
    }

}
class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] arg)
    {



        SmashPlayer m2k = new SmashPlayer(2,5);
        m2k.print();

    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121/finding-the-variable-name-passed-to-a-function-in-c-sharp gives you some options to achieve exactly what you've asked. Note that usually you would not use variable name for anything that can be displayed to user - depending on your actual goals there are more traditional solutions (starting with just adding `Name` property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible.
Simple example:

```
SmashPlayer m2k = new SmashPlayer(2,5);
SmashPlayer m2k_again = m2k;
```

Two variables, but it's the same instance of the class, what should you write as variable name? m2k or m2k_again ?

Look on answer of apocalypse for a possible solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41080725/5281555

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. You need to pass string to the constructor.

```
SmashPlayer m2k = new SmashPlayer (2, 5, "m2k");
```

Of course you need to add new parameter to that constructor and save it in instance field.

To avoid refactoring issues, you can use `nameof` operator.

```
SmashPlayer m2k = new SmashPlayer (2, 5, nameof (m2k));
```

Comment: what are refactoring issues?

Comment: @SuperMinefudge: For example it's when you rename your `m2k` variable to `newName`, and you will forget to update "m2k" string passed to the constructor. But if you use `nameof` operator - refactoring tool will be aware of that, and will also change `nameof(m2k)` to `nameof(newName)`.