# Can I add to the functionality of Grid so I can specify new Grid().BindIsVisible( xx );

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

Here is an example:

```
var grid3Help = 
   new Grid().Bind(Grid.IsVisibleProperty, nameof(HelpIconVisible), source: this)
```

Is there some way that I could add to Grid to make it possible for me to change this to:

```
var grid3Help = new Grid().BindIsVisible(HelpIconVisible, source: this)
```

Note that if possible I would like to have an extension method but I am not sure how to handle the setting of "source: this"

Comment: Are you looking for an extension method that does this?

Comment: yes, if that's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with creating and using a custom Grid (having the same properties as a `Grid`) instead:

```
public class CustomGrid: Grid
{
    public CustomGrid() : this() { }

    public void BindIsVisible(string bindobj, object sourceobj = null) {
          SetBinding(Grid.IsVisibleProperty, bindobj)
   }
}
```

```
var grid3Help = new CustomGrid().BindIsVisible(nameof(HelpIconVisible), source: this)
```

With extension method:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void BindIsVisible(this Grid grid, string boundproperty)
        {
            grid.SetBinding(VisualElement.IsVisibleProperty, boundproperty);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include the namespace: `using ExtensionMethods;`

In both cases you will have to send the parameter with `nameof()` otherwise you can try something a bit complicated [Finding the variable name passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121/finding-the-variable-name-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: Do you know how this could be done with an extension method?

Comment: @Alan2 I didn't understand what do you mean by source? also confused about Bind() exists or defined by you? I used SetBinding() but you can change it to adapt to your existing code if needed.