# Get variable name from object array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Can't find out how to get element variable name from array.

Need something like that:

```cs
var test = 1;
var test2 = "2";

var array = new object[]{test, test2};
foreach (var v in array)
{
 Debug.Log($"{v.ToString()} {v}")
}

// test 1
// test2 2
```

I need that in one method, lets call it "void CombineWithName(params object[] msg){}

Comment: why do you need to know the variable name?

Comment: @LeiYang for debug purposes

Comment: maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121/finding-the-variable-name-passed-to-a-function

Comment: There is no variable name in the array. You don't have an array of variables, you have an array of items.

Comment: @LeiYang thanks for the help. But my problem is that I'm trying to make a Logger which pass a (params object[] msg ) parameter to show the values to the console. In the end im getting "v" as a name and value.

Comment: @LeiYang 's link has answers related to your question.

Comment: `test` and `test2` are **variables**. As soon as you put these into an array the array itself has no information whatsoever where these values/references came from and to what they where assigned before ... inside the array best you can get is `index 0 = 1; index 1 = "2"`

Comment: @derHugo sad. If I want to make that i can store reference to the variable name i should create my own solution?

Comment: you would need e.g. `void Logger(params Tuple<string, object> args)` and pass in an array like e.g. `new[] { new Tuple<string, object>(nameof(test), test), new Tuple<string, object>(nameof(test2), test2) };` or use a wrapper class (same concept) ... there isn't really any way to get the original variable and field names as soon as you only have a `object[]`

Comment: @derHugo nah, thanks. I'm gonna write Logger messages too often with a different number. Not worth time. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible.  The names test1 and test2 are not stored in the variable array but pointers to the location of the data.  Using .net6 on .NETFiddle and the nameof method, the compiler tells you that the expression does not have a name.

[image: .NETFiddle]

Comment: I understand. But if this is not possible to catch the name from array somehow, then i will look in console at values

Answer (score 0):

The nameof operator allows you to get the name of a variable, type or member in string form without hard-coding it as a literal.

```
 var myVar = "ABC";
 Console.WriteLine(nameof(myVar));
```

Source: https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/363/basic-usage--printing-a-variable-name

**Edited:**

In your above approach, since you are directly mapping variables to an object, There is no way to figure out the variable that was used to set a element, unless you save that information in a separate array or collection (For debug purpose)

```
var test = 1;
var test2 = "2";

var array = new object[]{test, test2};

var arrayOfArrays = {
    new {Name = nameof(test), Array=test}
,   new {Name = nameof(test2), Array=test2}
};
foreach (var p in arrayOfArrays) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    ...
}
```

Comment: The code example in Edited section doesn't work as the constructor of `arrayOfArrays` is wrong. Also the name `arrayOfArrays` is misleading since it's not an array of arrays, which doesn't help when `var` is being used.

Comment: This doesn't compile ;) Of course you can do that .. but this doesn't really solve OP's attempt to have a `public void Logger(params object[] args){ /* log args with their names */ }` ... sure there are tons of ways if you manually pass in the names but I don't think this is really what OP wants. I'd say the answer is: What OP wants is not possible -> do something else.